# FireStore Transactions increment and decrement counter getting inconsistent result

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the code of transaction:-

```
var sfDocRef = firebaseCloudStore.collection("New").document(documentRef.get(pos))
    firebaseCloudStore.runTransaction(Transaction.Function {
        transaction - >
            val snapshot = transaction.get(sfDocRef)
        var newlikes: Double

        if (isliked == true) {
            newlikes = snapshot.getDouble("likes") !!+1
        } else {
            newlikes = snapshot.getDouble("likes") !!-1
        }
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, "likes", newlikes)
    }).addOnSuccessListener {

        var ref = firebaseCloudStore.collection("New").document(documentRef.get(pos)).get().addOnCompleteListener {
            list = it.result.toObject(New::class.java)
            arraylist.get(pos).likes = list.likes
            arraylist.get(pos).isliked = !arraylist.get(pos).isliked
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(pos)

        }
    }.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {
        e - > Log.w("TAG", "Transaction failure.", e)
    })
```

Here I have implemented FireStore transactions as mentioned in the docs but still getting inconsistent result , like if you press like button repeatedly fast then the result is either more larger or more less . Is there any error in code or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add `return null` inside `Transaction.Function.apply()` method, like [this](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/27bc210b9111eefc15a8aa75bb9917e91d7c47b1/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java#L504-L527)